# Eclipse AST method resolveTypeBinding always null even with K_COMPILATION_UNIT and BindingRecovery

Tags: java, parsing, eclipse-plugin, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm trying to extract the type of a method from a MethodInvocation object with the eclipse AST. I'm using the resolveTypeBinding but it is always returning null, I set the AST as:

```
    final ASTParser parser = ASTParser.newParser(AST.JLS8);
    parser.setBindingsRecovery(true);
    parser.setKind(ASTParser.K_COMPILATION_UNIT);
    parser.setSource(allProject.toCharArray());
    final CompilationUnit cu = (CompilationUnit) parser.createAST(null);
    InfoDetector infoDetector = new InfoDetector(cu);
    cu.accept(infoDetector);
```

InfoDetector is just the class where I override the visit methods.
The variable allProject is a parsed string of the content of all .java files in the project.

Answer (score 0):

Well that's not going to work. The parser kind tops out at a complete compilation unit--one source file. The bindings it wants to resolve would be some by letting it read other source and class files as set up through the environment-related methods.